# Find items by property in JLIST

Tags: java, swing, iteration, jlist

I have a JList peopleList populated with a objects of Person class

```
class Person
{
  private String name;
  private String age;

  private void setName(String value)
  {
    name = value;
  }

  private String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Current to find a person with name I do

```
public boolean personByNameExists(String name)
{
  for(int index = 0 ; index < peopleList .getModel().getSize() ; index ++)
  {
    Person pl = (Person) peopleList .getModel().getElementAt(index);

    if( p1.getName().equals(name))
    {
      return  true;
    }
  }
}
```

I am wondering if there is way to do the same operation with out going through the whole list. I am from .Net back ground and in C# I would use LINQ is there something similar in Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [filter and sort list using google collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312849/filter-and-sort-list-using-google-collections)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a typical [filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28higher-order_function%29) functionality.

I'd recommend you look at Google Guava's:

- [`Collections2.filter(Collection, Predicate)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29),
- [`Iterables.filter(Iterable, Class)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class%29),
- or [`Iterables.filter(Iterable, Predicate)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29)

You can find more info [here](http://codemunchies.com/2009/11/functional-java-filtering-and-ordering-with-google-collections-part-3/) or even look at this SO question (your question is a duplicate):

- [filter and sort list using google collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312849/filter-and-sort-list-using-google-collections)

**Update:** As kleopatra made me realize, you might be using a normal `ListModel`.

You could specifiy a custom model when creating your JList, that either:

- implements a Collection or Iterable interface,
- or provides a method to return a view of the data filtered by the property you want.

Comment: afaics, the question is about Swing ListModel

Comment: @kleopatra: darn, you're right. I had gotten too much used to have an adapter for this.

Comment: You can use the above methods if the model of your `JList` is backed by a `List`, which isn't that far-fetched

Comment: @Robin: yes, but kleopatra is right: the default Models do not implement any of the collection interfaces and won't be usable this way. The OP could, however, write a custom Model implementation to satisfy this, or to provide additional methods to access customized views of the data.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on the use-case. If you just want to find an entry on the model side, you can keep looping over your `ListModel`, or loop over the data structure behind the `ListModel` which can be a regular `List` implementation, and then you can use the methods suggested by haylem.

If you want to search on your `JList`, and present the search result visually to the user (for example highlight them and scroll to the relevant entry) I would highly recommend taking a look at the SwingX project which supports this out-of-the-box