# Remove element from certain array using JAVA?

Tags: java

Problem: Given an array and a value, remove all instances of that value in place and return the new length. The order of elements can be changed. It doesn't matter what you leave beyond the new length.

I want to solve this question by using JAVA ArrayList. And by code is listed as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class removeElement {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public int removeElement(int[] A, int elem) {

    int length = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Arrays.sort(A);
    //add elements in A to al
    for(int i:A){
        al.add(i);
    }
    //Remember arraylist's remove() is to remove first occurance of elements. 
    if(al.contains(elem)&&al.size() == 1){
        return 0;
    }
    while(al.contains(elem)){
        al.remove(elem);
    }
    length = al.size();
    return length;

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    removeElement re = new removeElement();
    int[] A = {3, 3};
    int element = 3;
    System.out.println(re.removeElement(A, element));

}

}
```

The result shows that:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:412)
    at removeElement.removeElement(removeElement.java:24)
    at removeElement.main(removeElement.java:35)
```

Can I use JAVA ArrayList to solve this problem? Or should I solve it in another way? Waiting for your reply. Thanks a lot!

Comment: even though it would not be the answer to your particular question, I would rather use Predicates for this purpose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312849/filter-and-sort-list-using-google-collections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are two overloaded `remove()` methods in [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which one accepting [int](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) parameter as an index of the object and the other one accept [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) as parameter to remove.

You have use wrapper object to remove that element which is int. Otherwise, the overloaded [`remove(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) will be called and you don't have any element at index of 3, So, you got `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
while(al.contains(elem)){
   al.remove(new Integer(elem));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it simpler.

```
public int[] removeElement(int[] input, int deleteMe) {
    List<Integer> result = new LinkedList();

    for(int i=0;input.length;i++)
        if(deleteMe!=input[i])
            result.add(input[i]);

    return result.toArray(input);
}
```

Comment: It is really efficient!

Comment: You're welcome, so it might be marked as proper answer maybe ;)