# How to itereate through elements in list java

Tags: java

I have a list: [exA,exB,exC,inA,exC].
I want to remove all elements with ex in it. How?
this is the code I have tried.

```
for (int i = 0; i < grades.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            
            }
```

Comment: What does this ArrayList contains?

Comment: The code you've "tried" doesn't deal with any list so what did you actually do? So far you're just iterating over `i` and `j`. Since you want to remove code what you're trying should at least contain a call to `List.remove(...)` (or better use an interator and call `remove()` on that - the details are quite well documented).

Comment: For what is the inner for loop? is it a list of strings?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried some code, but it did not work. The list name is grades [exA,exB,exC,inA,exC] . It needs to iterate through all the indexes. If it find ex, it need to eliminate the whole word.

Comment: You can use an iterator to iterate through the list, use contains or startsWith on each word to check if it contains the substring ('ex' in this case). If yes, call remove on the list to eliminate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove element from certain array using JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439591/remove-element-from-certain-array-using-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose the elements of the list are String.You could do that with the help of  Collection::removeIf method

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("exA");
        list.add("exBff");
        list.add("inA");
        list.add("exC");

        list.removeIf(element -> element.contains("ex"));


        list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output

```
inA
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Please run this code and check why this will not work.

Comment: Lets say I have [exA,exB,maA,maB] and want to remove ma or exA.

Comment: You just changed your question now. Are you asking to change just only one specific element or elements that contain ex.

Comment: Lets say I click on a button on javaFX. The button can give value [exA,exB,exC] for three buttons. It can also give for [inA,inB,inC]. When I click on random buttons I may get  [exA,exB,InA,InB] I want it to to remove the elements which contain the last index. This instance it is all elements with In in it. I have another one to. [mat3A] and [mat1A]. So I click here I can get [exA,inC,mat3A,mat1A,mat3B]. I want It to recognize the elements until the Capital letter in the last index, and then remove all the ones containing that.

Comment: @Dren's solution will still work for you in that case. Just pass the substring to a function with the above code, where the substring will replace "ex"

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to remove elements from the list during iteration. So,

- Iterate through the list.
- Check if str contains any 'ex'.
- if no, then populate items into a new list.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("exA");
list.add("exB");
list.add("inA");
list.add("exC");

List<String> modifiedList = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String str:list) {
    if(!str.contains("ex"))
        modifiedList.add(str);
}

//if necessary then assign new list to the old list
list = modifiedList;
```